# How to recursively read local files and directories in web browser using File System Access API

Tags: javascript, web, browser, file-system-access-api

I need to read all the files and directories of a folder opened with the new File System Access API for the web. I am able to read a directory but don't know how to continue recursively on an elegant way

```js
      try {
        const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
        const files = []
        for await (let [name, handle] of directoryHandle) {
          const kind = handle.kind
          files.push({
            name,
            handle,
            kind,
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

two steps, define one function that should take a directory and return all files and folders recursively as below

```
    async function listAllFilesAndDirs(dirHandle) {
    const files = [];
    for await (let [name, handle] of dirHandle) {
        const {kind} = handle;
        if (handle.kind === 'directory') {
            files.push({name, handle, kind});
            files.push(...await listAllFilesAndDirs(handle));
        } else {
            files.push({name, handle, kind});
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

then invoke this function from your code as below

```
async function onClickHandler(e) {
    try {
        const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
        const files = await listAllFilesAndDirs(directoryHandle);
        console.log('files', files);
    }catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code live: https://showdirectorypicker.glitch.me/